# Crouton is overlaying the toolbar on the StackExchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

The Crouton should ideally display underneath the toolbar, for context-sensitive updates that don't block content actions.

I apologise if this is a double-post, because I think I initially submitted it to the wrong community.

[image]

Comment: Rather than cross posting, you should have just flagged your [MSO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293504/crouton-is-overlaying-the-toolbar-on-the-android-app) for migration.

Comment: Ah cool. I didn't know that. Will I delete this one and flag the other so?

Comment: Just leave it be for now.  If/when the other gets migrated, they can be merged or closed as dups.

Comment: Bah! Switching over to `Toolbar` has caused me so much grief. Thanks for reporting this, will fix it up for the next update :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.85.

As Paul described, the issue is that the crouton wasn't attached to anything in the activity.  I've fixed this in three places:

1. Any activity that uses `BaseActivity`.  (feed, question list, question, ...) This already had a content `FrameLayout` around the body fragment.
2. Asking/Editing a question.  I wrapped its three fragments in a `FrameLayout` and discovered some assumptions we had around the truly shocking behavior of the support `FragmentTransaction` and the behavior of multiple fragments.
3. Adding/Editing an answer.  Same as 2.

There may be other areas that don't use this base layout (like registration) which will still get obscured in the toolbar.  This is the bulk of the issue though.

Answer (score 2):

The Crouton library displays over the actionbar/toolbar when called from an Activity's context, without the viewgroup parameter.

Creating a small FrameLayout above your main content and attaching the crouton to this will fix the issue.

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/crouton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Note: choosing `wrap-content` for your layout-height will cause the crouton to be consumed by the layout before it is properly cancelled, causing double notifications or jerky behaviour.

```
Crouton.makeText(
      MainActivity.this,
      croutonText,
      croutonStyle,
      R.id.crouton
 ).show();
```

Alternatively, you can directly attach it to the content view, if you wish to do it programmatically:

```
// Find content view and cast to ViewGroup, to attach crouton
View homeBtn = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
Crouton.makeText(
      MainActivity.this,
      croutonText,
      croutonStyle,
      (ViewGroup) homeBtn)
 ).show();
```